# Clicking add 3 "projects" doesn't do anything after you've clicked it more than once

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

On your edit cv page right side there is a section to **Improve your CV**.  After you've clicked the projects link once any succinct clicks does absolutely nothing, should anchor you back to open source section but doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repro'd and a fix is building out now. Thanks!